# Has Linq b-tree (b+, b* whatever) about the operand collection like DB?

Tags: c#, linq

I just wonder the Linq's inner operation compare to traditional RDB.
As I know, RDB has b-tree and uses the tree to operate like SELECT, JOIN, GROUP BY, etc.

Therefore, Linq's expression looks like SQL, and I think that would need similar operations.

At First, I guess it might be different ways, because RDB is to save many data in files, but Linq is just to operate in memory.
However, I am a beginner in C# - I am a Java Programmer -, and other person who experienced C# says Linq is for a large data, that shows bad performance in small collections.

If Linq is designed for large data, Linq might have their operand as a tree structure, and it operates SELECT, JOIN, GROUP BY like RDB. Or, I guess, Linq just translate SQL grammer to functional operations for lazy loading without a tree structure.

In short, Linq makes it's operand b-tree? If not, how does Linq deal with it's operand? and is it some documents to get clues?

Comment: Linq is not "just to operate in memory", it's mostly about creating Expressions which can be used to query any IQueryable data source including in-memory and in-database. How those expressions translate depends on the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of LINQ methods are simple iterators that make a trivial calculation, selection or projection. This is the case for `Select`, `Any`, `First`, `Max` etc. Others like `OrderBy` and `Reverse` are using an internal buffer to rearrange the elements. Others like `GroupBy` are using a lookup (something similar to a Dictionary) to create the groupings efficiently. You can study the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html) yourself and see the inner workings of each method.